# Given a binary tree and a number ‘S’, find all paths from root-to-leaf such that the sum of all the node values of each path equals ‘S’

Tags: python, list, recursion, depth-first-search

The example below is from a source online and what I'm not sure of is why we need to append to `allPaths` a new copy of `currentPath`. I thought that in deleting the last element as we go back up the recursive call stack by doing `del currentPath[-1]` makes sure that we are not adding the previous path to the new path

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right


def find_paths(root, required_sum):
  allPaths = []
  find_paths_recursive(root, required_sum, [], allPaths)
  return allPaths


def find_paths_recursive(currentNode, required_sum, currentPath, allPaths):
  if currentNode is None:
    return

  # add the current node to the path
  currentPath.append(currentNode.val)

  # if the current node is a leaf and its value is equal to required_sum, save the current path
  if currentNode.val == required_sum and currentNode.left is None and currentNode.right is None:
    allPaths.append(list(currentPath))
  else:
    # traverse the left sub-tree
    find_paths_recursive(currentNode.left, required_sum -
                         currentNode.val, currentPath, allPaths)
    # traverse the right sub-tree
    find_paths_recursive(currentNode.right, required_sum -
                         currentNode.val, currentPath, allPaths)

  # remove the current node from the path to backtrack,
  # we need to remove the current node while we are going up the recursive call stack.
  del currentPath[-1]


def main():

  root = TreeNode(12)
  root.left = TreeNode(7)
  root.right = TreeNode(1)
  root.left.left = TreeNode(4)
  root.right.left = TreeNode(10)
  root.right.right = TreeNode(5)
  required_sum = 23
  print("Tree paths with required_sum " + str(required_sum) +
        ": " + str(find_paths(root, required_sum)))


main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to realise that during the whole process there is only *one* `currentPath` list. It is the one that is created in the initial call:

```
find_paths_recursive(root, required_sum, [], allPaths)
#                                        ^^---here!
```

All that happens to that single list is that elements are appended to it, and then deleted from it again (when backtracking). It continually grows and shrinks, grows and shrinks,... throughout its lifetime. But it is the same, single list instance.

If you were to append that list to `allPaths` without taking a copy, i.e. like this:

```
allPaths.append(currentPath)
```

...then realise that while that list is a member of `allPaths`, it *will* be mutated by future `append` and `delete` actions on it! Even more: as the above statement is executed again later on:

```
allPaths.append(currentPath)
```

... exactly *the same* list is appended that is already in `allPaths`... because there is only one `currentPath` list! So you'll end up with `allPaths` having repeated references to one and the same list.

Concluding: it is important to take a copy of `currentPath` which will not be mutated any more by the future mutations on `currentPath`. It is like taking a snapshot of the *current* state of `currentPath`.

Answer (score 1):

The `find_paths_recursive` function was designed such that appending to `allPaths` is the way to return the results to the caller.

```
def find_paths(root, required_sum):
  allPaths = []
  find_paths_recursive(root, required_sum, [], allPaths)
  return allPaths
```

Here in `find_paths`, `allPaths` is passed to `find_paths_recursive` as an empty list and after it is done, it will contain the results (paths from root to leaf which fulfill the described condition).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend breaking the problem down into separate parts. First we write a generic `paths` function -

```py
def paths (t = None, p = ()):
  if not t:
    return
  elif t.left or t.right:
    yield from paths(t.left, (*p, t.val))
    yield from paths(t.right, (*p, t.val))
  else:
    yield (*p, t.val)
```

```py
mytree = TreeNode \
  ( 12
  , TreeNode(7, TreeNode(4))
  , TreeNode(1, TreeNode(10)) 
  )
```

Now we can see how `paths` works -

```py
for p in paths(mytree):
  print(p)
```

```py
(12, 7, 4)
(12, 1, 10)
```

Now we can write `solver` that specializes `paths` -

```py
def solver (t = None, q = 0):
  for p in paths(t):
    if sum(p) == q:
      yield p
```

`solver` is a generator which yields *all* possible solutions. It is a good choice for programs like this because you can pause/cancel the solving as soon as you found the solution(s) you are looking for -

```py
for sln in solver(mytree, 23):
  print(sln)
```

The output isn't particularly interesting because each branch in `mytree` sums to 23 -

```py
(12, 7, 4)
(12, 1, 10)
```

If we make `anothertree` with different values, we can see more interesting output -

```py
anothertree = TreeNode \
  ( 1
  , TreeNode(7, TreeNode(4), TreeNode(5))
  , TreeNode(9, TreeNode(2), TreeNode(7))
  )
```

```py
for sln in solver(anothertree, 12):
  print(sln)
```

```py
(1, 7, 4)
(1, 9, 2)
```